# GNUMakefile and gcc: resolving the order of conflicting "-std=c++" requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile, c++17

Many packages these days come with a configuration utility to help set compiler requirements. I can give more specific examples if required, but a Makefile that links against two libraries might have something like:

```
CPPFLAGS += $(shell PackageA-config --cflags)
CPPFLAGS += $(shell PackageB-config --cflags)

%.o : %.cc 
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now let's say that PackageA requires at least c++11, and PackageB requires c++17, i.e. `PackageA-config --cflags` would yield `-std=c++11` and `PackageB-config --cflags` would yield `-std=c++17`.  gcc will use whichever flag came last, and since all the standards are backwards compatible, this is fine and dandy.

But what if I write my Makefile in the "wrong" order, so that PackageB comes first? Now PackageA's `-std=c++11` flag is the one that actually gets used, and compilation fails.

Is there a way to tell gcc to take the highest flag given, rather than just use the last one?  If not, is there a standard way to tackle this headache?  Failing everything else, can some guru come up with a fix by manipulating the Makefile variable?

Comment: The cheeky answer is just to stick in `CPPFLAGS += -stdc++17` at the end. Problem solved.

Comment: @Barry yes, except my particular use case is scientific grid computing where one usually builds against much older compilers. Even c++11 support is still not a given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) that are pretty useful to know.

You can filter out the `-std=` flag:

```
filtered := $(filter -std=%,$(CPPFLAGS))
```

And then sort it in lexical order:

```
sorted := $(sort $(filtered))
```

And then just take the last one:

```
highest := $(lastword $(sorted))
```

Or, all in one go:

```
best_std_version := $(lastword $(sort $(filter -std=%,$(CPPFLAGS))))
```

---

This won't work if one of the standard versions is 98. It's like the Y2K bug all over again. But you can deal with that by filtering it out.

Comment: Or replace `98` with `03` which means the same thing and sorts correctly. To be really safe, you'd also want to replace `-ansi` with `-std=c++03`, and then punch whoever used the `-ansi` flag.